# Chart.js angular8 Y axis ticks

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

How to dynamically update Y-axis ticks in chart.js. I have tried updating it using the below commands:

```
this.chartOptions.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = 10;
this.chartOptions.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max = 18;
```

Comment: Hard to understand your issue (Add basic code example). Set max/min bar range like this: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#axis-range-settings

Comment: For the first time, the Y-axis ticks appear. But if  I Change them later using the above commands the Y-axis ticks are not changing.

Comment: Anyway, to add an example? (Basic codepen. This issue not related to angular).

Answer (score 0):

After changing the chart options, you need to invoke `chart.update()`. For more details, consult [Updating Options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#updating-options) from the Chart.js documentation.

Please run the following code sample and press the <kbd>Update</kbd> button to see how it works.

```js
function updateYAxis() {
  chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = 20;
  chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max = 100;
  chart.update();
}

const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First Dataset',
      data: [30, 59, 80],
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)'],
      borderColor: ['rgb(255, 99, 132)', 'rgb(255, 159, 64)', 'rgb(255, 205, 86)', 'rgb(75, 192, 192)'],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: { 
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-width: 300px;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="10" height="5"></canvas>
<button onclick="updateYAxis()">Update</button>
```